# Cross-browser testing with Cypress without installation of browsers

Tags: browser, automated-tests, cross-browser, cypress

As I am learning Cypress, I am trying to run a simple test in Firefox and Chrome. Unfortunately, I don‘t know how to set it up so that I can run it from the command line, instead of installing the browsers.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

No matter if you use the visual Cypress Test Runner (`cypress open`) or run your tests headless via the Command Line (`cypress run`), the desired browser must be installed. The only exception is the Electron browser that comes with Cypress. The Electron browser is a version of Chromium and does not need to be installed separately.

You can find detailed information about this topic here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers#Browsers